# Running powershell script from explorer = execution policy error

Tags: powershell

1. In windows 7 final I've done: Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
2. In windows explorer, I select a script.ps1 file, select open with, put in c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
3. A powershell window flashes briefly with an error about execution policy.

Scripts run fine from within powershell. How can I run them from windows explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. There were clues in "about_Execution_Policies" help item. The process execution policy must have been more restrictive which was overrides the localmachine policy which got set by the standard Set-ExecutionPolicy command.

Group policy overrides all this. You get a template to set that from [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2917a564-dbbc-4da7-82c8-fe08b3ef4e6d&DisplayLang=en), ignore the part of the page that says this applies only to win xp, thats wrong. That page and above help file have the rest of the needed instructions.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it's an execution policy error? If it's PowerShell v2, try including the `-File` parameter before the file name:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -File "%1"
```